# Purpose of task host container in SSIS

Tags: ssis

If a task host container contains just one task and nothing else, why do you need it? Could you not just have the task stand by itself?

I am going by the description provided on this page.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139911(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Task Host Container is not in the Toolbox, but each Task will be placed in its own Task Host Container by default."-http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DonnyJohns/ssas/1669/ssis-package-containers-part-1-task-host-containers

Answer (score 0):

Using BIDS/SSDT/Visual Studio to design your packages, you will never see a Task Host Container on your canvas. As a consumer of the tools, you just see Tasks. If you are developing your own custom Tasks, or are interacting with SSIS packages through the object model, *then* you're going to be concerned with the Tasks Hosts and the object model in general.

If your question is about why the integration services team designed the class as they did, then we'll need to close your question as unanswerable.

Comment: Mine was more a question of what its purpose is